# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billOfLadingCallerImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\BKR059\Documents\GIT\gcd-compliance\service\target\classes\net\apmoller\crb\gcd\microservices\compliance\callers\BillOfLadingCallerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [net/apmoller/crb/gcd/microservices/compliance/config/ComplianceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)  at net.apmoller.crb.gcd.microservices.compliance.ComplianceApplication.main(ComplianceApplication.java:20) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [net/apmoller/crb/gcd/microservices/compliance/config/ComplianceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)  ... 19 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)  ... 33 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:403)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359)   at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389)     at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)  at net.apmoller.crb.gcd.microservices.compliance.config.ComplianceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e10ada0.webClient(<generated>)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)  ... 34 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)   at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)   at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)     at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:908)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1228)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)   ... 50 more

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billOfLadingCallerImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\BKR059\Documents\GIT\gcd-compliance\service\target\classes\net\apmoller\crb\gcd\microservices\compliance\callers\BillOfLadingCallerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [net/apmoller/crb/gcd/microservices/compliance/config/ComplianceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billOfLadingCallerImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\BKR059\Documents\GIT\gcd-compliance\service\target\classes\net\apmoller\crb\gcd\microservices\compliance\callers\BillOfLadingCallerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [net/apmoller/crb/gcd/microservices/compliance/config/ComplianceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)  at net.apmoller.crb.gcd.microservices.compliance.ComplianceApplication.main(ComplianceApplication.java:20) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [net/apmoller/crb/gcd/microservices/compliance/config/ComplianceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)  ... 19 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)  ... 33 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.complianceConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:403)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359)   at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389)     at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)  at net.apmoller.crb.gcd.microservices.compliance.config.ComplianceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e10ada0.webClient(<generated>)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)  ... 34 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}"  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)  at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)   at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)   at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)     at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:908)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1228)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)   ... 50 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Show us some code. The issue is with the instantiation of the `billOfLadingCallerImpl` bean.

Comment: Please reformat your log and add some explanation.

By the way, your log actually says the problem.

Could not resolve placeholder 'gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId' in value "${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}

Answer (score 1):

As the log says, you are missing
`gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId in value ${gcd.billoflading.bolDetailsByBolId}`
in the property file you use in the project.

Defining it should solve the problem.